Maximally "unexpected" binary time series
I'm sure this idea isn't new. Suppose a computer program has to predict
a binary time series by calculating the most probable continuation
(this is a widely known "joke" if you want to show a human the inability
of generating a random sequence). You like to troll the computer,
compute the most "probable" continuation beforehand and say the opposite bit.
Unfortunately I'm not even remotely expert on entropy measurements of binary time series (algorithmic compressibility is the key here).
Illustration: Assume you take a very primitive measure $m$ - number of pre-period
bits plus bit length of period. $10$ ($m=2$) is more random than $11$ ($m=1$). But $100$ and $101$ both have $m=2$. Which is more random?
Assuming some decent algorithmic complexity measure instead, what sequence is generated?
